# unity parent relative to child position and rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've looked around for some ideas on this to no avail.  I have a scene in unity where a parent has four children positioned and rotated in relation to the parent (though not necessarily the same position and rotation as the parent).  After moving and rotating the parent,  the children should follow the parent, and reset their position and rotation in locally similar way to parent as before, preserving a similar formation.  In particular, I can get the children to follow the parent, but once the parent reaches their destination, I don't know how to reset the children to their appropriate formation positions and rotations once the goal is reached.  I'm not looking for someone to answer my question as much as a headstart on how to make this happen.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a script on your parent,

One approach will be to store the `Transforms` of the `Children` before the Parent starts to move and after reaching the destination, apply the `Transform` back to the children :)

[Child's transform is relative to the parent, so the child will be displaced if the parent is rotated since child is not at (0,0,0) relative to the parent]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it's much appreciated.